# multiplying a vector and a matrix using for nested for loops

Tags: python

I want to write a function matvec_row_variant_scalar(A,x) that implements the scalar-wise, row-variant of the matrix-vector multiplication, where A is a 2D array, and x is a 1D array. It MUST use two nested loops and scalar-wise access to the entries of    and   .
this is what i have tried.

```
def matvec_row_variant_scalar(A,x):
    y = np.zeros(x.shape)
    for i in range(A.shape[0]):
        for j in range(A.shape[0]):
            A[i,j] =int(x[j])*A[i,j]
            y[j] = A[i,:].sum()
    return y      

A= np.array([[1,0,0],[0,,0],[0,0,1]])
x= np.array([[1], [2], [3]])
print(matvec_row_variant_scalar(A,x))
```

Answer (score 0):

I understand you want a column-vector `b = A * x` where `b[i] = (A[i, :] * x[i]).sum()`, where `x` is also a column-vector. You don't really need a loop for this, because numpy can do this for you without loops much faster.

```
A = np.array([[1,0,0],[0,1,0],[0,0,1]])
x = np.array([[1], [2], [3]])

b = (A * x).sum(axis=1, keepdims=True)

# b = array([[1],
#       [2],
#       [3]])
```

Alternatively, you can simplify your problem before calculating it:
`(A[i, :] * x[i]).sum()` is the same as `A[i, :].sum() * x[i]`, so you can sum across the rows of `A` *first* and then multiply by `x` to get the same result.

```
b = A.sum(axis=1, keepdims=True) * x
```

However, since you must have two loops, (Note that this will be much slower especially for larger arrays)

```
y = np.zeros(x.shape)
for i in range(A.shape[0]): # iterate over rows
    for j in range(A.shape[1]): # iterate over columns
        y[i, 0] = y[i, 0] + x[i, 0] * A[i,j] # Keep adding x[i] * A[i, j] to y[i] 

# y = array([[1.],
#       [2.],
#       [3.]])
```

---

Speed comparison:

```
import timeit
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

sizes = [1, 5, 10, 50, 100, 500, 1000, 5000, 10000]

def mult1(A, x):
    return (A * x).sum(axis=1, keepdims=True)

def mult2(A, x):
    return A.sum(axis=1, keepdims=True) * x
    
def mult3(A, x):
    y = np.zeros(x.shape)
    for i in range(A.shape[0]): # iterate over rows
        for j in range(A.shape[1]): # iterate over columns
            y[i, 0] = y[i, 0] + x[i, 0] * A[i,j] # Keep adding x[i] * A[i, j] to y[i]
    return y

time_vals = np.zeros((len(size),3))

for i, size in enumerate(sizes):
    reps = 10 if size < 1000 else 1
    print(sizes, reps)
    
    A = np.random.random((size, size))
    x = np.random.random((size, 1))
    time_vals[i, 0] = timeit.timeit("mult1(A, x)", setup="from __main__ import A, x, mult1", number=reps) / reps
    time_vals[i, 1] = timeit.timeit("mult2(A, x)", setup="from __main__ import A, x, mult2", number=reps) / reps
    time_vals[i, 2] = timeit.timeit("mult3(A, x)", setup="from __main__ import A, x, mult3", number=reps) / reps

plt.plot(sizes, time_vals[:, 0], label="mult1")
plt.plot(sizes, time_vals[:, 1], label="mult2")
plt.plot(sizes, time_vals[:, 2], label="mult3")
```

Gives this plot. The iterative approach is consistently 1+ order of magnitude slower than the vectorized approach for arrays of significant size.
[image]